# Change order of tabs in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I want my custom object to be the first tab on the navigation bar in Salesforce1. How do I set that up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom objects will show up in the menu because the "Smart Search Items" are added in the mobile navigation section.

Controlling in which order these objects appear is handled by "**pinning**" objects in the search results of the regular Salesforce web version.
So in regular Salesforce, search on anything.
In the resultspage, hover over the several objects at the left and you will notice a pin icon appearing. 
Click on the pin icon to pin an object to the top.
The order in which the pinned objects appear there will be the order in which you see your objects appear in the "Smart Search Items" section of Salesforce1. (hence the name smart search items)

[image: pinning smart search items]

Flexipages are indeed a second option but be a bit carefull with these. I have noticed that sometimes, Salesforce1 can act a bit strange (slow) if flexipages are set as the first entry of the mobile navigation.

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

In the mobile navigation screen (Setup->Mobile Administration->Mobile Navigation), use the Up and Down arrows to dictate the order of the tabs displayed within Salesforce1.  Once you do this, you'll have to refresh Salesforce1 to pick up the changes.

[image]

Comment: What if all my objects don't show up on that page as available tabs?

Comment: Take a look at the [salesforce1 developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_introduction.htm) for documentation on what items will show up on that page.  In short though, you will need to set up a VF tab (make sure the VF page is mobile-enabled), or a Flexipage.