# Salesforce1 Mobile Navigation settings Custom object tab not appearing

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am planing to add one of our custom object tab under APP section in salesforce1 navigation menu. To do this I need to place custom object tab below smart search in Mobile Navigation settings. But my custom object tab is not listed under available section inside Mobile Navigation settings. The tab is already created and added to my available tab in  full sales force. Anything missing or something else has to be done ? Or is it a restriction the standard and custom objects will appear only inside the smart search Items.

Comment: Permission issue for object or tab on the logged in user profile ?

Comment: No the user is having enough permissions

Answer (score 1):

The smart search items will by default show all objects (both standard and custom) to which a user has access too.

The user himself can control in which order he sees the objects by pinning objects after doing a search in regular Salesforce.
I have explained about this pinning mechanism in more detail here:

[Change order of tabs in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/26996/change-order-of-tabs-in-salesforce1/27080#27080)

Also mentioned in my answer there, if the way the smart search items with the pinning isn't acceptable for your business you can have more control over your menu and which objects appear or not by working with flexipages.
I have written an article about that which you can find here:

[Flexipages: The Hidden Gem in Saleforce 1](http://www.absi.be/article.aspx?id=1121)